# Pivoting and partitioning Query to get Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, row-number

I tried the HackerRank question below where the Names have to be pivoted on the Occupations.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem

I found a solution, but don't understand how it works specifically why are the other names returning in the result when taking a max on the names.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Occupations
(
    Name varchar(25),
    Occupation varchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Samantha', 'Doctor')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Julia', 'Actor')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Maria', 'Actor')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Meera', 'Singer')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Ashley', 'Professor')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Ketty', 'Professor')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Christeen', 'Singer')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Jane', 'Actor')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Jenny', 'Doctor')
GO
INSERT INTO Occupations VALUES('Priya', 'Singer')
GO
```

Solution:

```
SELECT [Doctor], [Professor], [Singer],[Actor] 
FROM 
(   
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name ASC) AS RowNumber, * 
    FROM Occupations) as tempTable 
    PIVOT 
    (
        MAX(Name) FOR OCCUPATION IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor])
    ) AS pivotTable
```

So the way I understand this query gets executed is that the rows get partitioned by Occupation ordered by the name and then the max names gets pivoted on the Occupations.  So how does the query still return the other names by occupation?

Comment: The way PIVOT works is it groups on the rest of the columns that were not in the PIVOT. Here you've assigned a row_number() partitioned by occupation, so each name in an occupation is assigned a number (1, 2, 3, etc...). The pivot will find the max(name) for each occupation with rownumber = 1, max(name) for each occupation with rownumber = 2, etc... Essentially, the row_number() window function is splitting the names into distinct groups that all get returned as a result.

Comment: It might help to think of it in terms of writing it without PIVOT. For example, `SELECT [Doctor] = MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN Name END), [Professor] = MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Professor' THEN Name END), [Singer] = MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Singer' THEN Name END), [Actor] = MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Actor' THEN Name END) FROM (SELECT *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) FROM Occupations) AS O GROUP BY RowNumber;`

Comment: That's a good explanation.  I didn't realize PIVOT groups on the columns that aren't included in the PIVOT.

Comment: Does the pivot query and the group by query that you wrote work the same way?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. You'll probably see similar execution plans for both if you run both of them for a query as simple as this one. But the principle behind them is the same regardless. If you look for examples of how to pivot in SQL Server on SO, you'll find many similar examples using `CASE` and aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

/*using MS SQL server*/

```
SELECT [Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor] from (select row_number() over (partition by occupation order by Name)rownumber,name,occupation from occupations group by occupation,name)as table2 pivot(max(name) for occupation in ([Doctor],[professor],[Singer],[Actor])) as tab1 order by rownumber
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to offer better indentation for readability?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    Doctor,
    Professor,
    Singer,
    Actor
from (
    select
        NameOrder,
        max(case Occupation when 'Doctor' then Name end) as Doctor,
        max(case Occupation when 'Professor' then Name end) as Professor,
        max(case Occupation when 'Singer' then Name end) as Singer,
        max(case Occupation when 'Actor' then Name end) as Actor
    from (
            select
                Occupation,
                Name,
                row_number() over(partition by Occupation order by Name ASC) as NameOrder
            from Occupations
         ) as NameLists
    group by NameOrder
    ) as Names
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.